# SonarLint plugin IntelliJ with no authentication

Tags: authentication, sonarqube, sonarlint

Is it possible to connect to a remote `SonarQube 5.6.1` server using the `SonarLint 3.0.0` plugin for `IntelliJ 2017.1` without using authentication by default? Currently the plugin seems to want either `username/password` OR `token`

Comment: i just left those fields empty, and it is using anonymous login

Comment: @SimonSchrottner it blocks the wizard from moving forward if there are not values in that setting.

Comment: You are totally right, did not see the update in the wizard - i will post a hack as answer :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a hack which you can use:

Normally sonarLint stores the information in your `IntelliJConfiguration-directory` in `config/options/sonarlint.xml` - you can simply paste following configuration into that file:

```
<application>
  <component name="SonarLintGlobalSettings">
    <option name="sonarQubeServers">
      <list>
        <SonarQubeServer>
          <option name="hostUrl" value="<your-server-url>" />
          <option name="name" value="test" />
          <option name="login" value="" />
          <password />
          <organizationKey />
        </SonarQubeServer>
      </list>
    </option>
  </component>
</application>
```

which is the basic configuration for a server without authentication.

// EDIT: It seems like this was an intended change by sonarSource to sonarLint - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sonarlint/xnpQmXN8NEo - is the mailing list discussion about this

Comment: ah very nice.  Would I be correct in guessing the key to enable a proxy is "proxy"

Comment: <option name="enableProxy" value="true" /> - if you need a special option for proxy let me know, i can try that on the old plugin version